# Rails app (Nginx / Passenger) freezes up for 20+ minutes after capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I have a Rails 4 app that is experiencing a problem with capistrano deployment. After each capistrano deploy, the web app hangs (http requests are on hold and the website cannot be reached via browser) for a long period of time, **in some cases up to 20 or even 30 minutes.**

I like to think the deploy is fairly standard. The general procedure is:

- `git push` the repo to remote server
- standard capistrano `:publishing`
- Bundle install with `capistrano/bundler`
- `touch tmp/restart`

And there's nothing tricky in the `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
```

Running a `cap server deploy` completes successfully and returns in about 10 seconds. But after it's done, the server goes down and stays down ("freezes up") for a really long time, until finally it comes back and the new version is deployed.

I am able to `ssh` into the server (although the prompt is super laggy) while this is happening and I can see that all of its resources are being used up by ruby / Passenger RackApp:

top:

```
>top
PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
.. .. ..   ..  ..  . 50.1 18.4 ..    ruby
.. .. ..   ..  ..  . 49.8 18.7 ..    ruby
.. .. ..   ..  ..  . 49.9 21.1 ..    ruby
.. .. ..   ..  ..  . 49.5 20.9 ..    ruby
```

This server has two cores so that is all of its available CPU.

ps aux shows several instances of Passenger RackApp all churning away:

```
>ps aux
USER PID  %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
user .... 11.0 18.3 ..  ..  ..  ..   ..    2:05 Passenger RackApp: /www/myRailsApp/current
user .... 12.1 18.3 ..  ..  ..  ..   ..    1:35 Passenger RackApp: /www/myRailsApp/current
user .... 12.1 20.3 ..  ..  ..  ..   ..    1:33 Passenger RackApp: /www/myRailsApp/current
user .... 14.7 21.0 ..  ..  ..  ..   ..    1:21 Passenger RackApp: /www/myRailsApp/current
user .... 5.6 12.5  ..  ..  ..  ..   ..    0:24 Passenger RackApp: /www/myRailsApp/current
user .... 5.8 6.6   ..  ..  ..  ..   ..    0:07 Passenger AppPreloader: /www/myRailsApp/current
user .... 0.7 7.6   ..  ..  ..  ..   ..    0:01 Passenger RackApp: /www/myRailsApp/current
```

Passenger-status looks generally like this:

```
>passenger-status
Version : 4.0.41
Date    : 2014-07-23 15:25:11 +0000
Instance: 19086
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 3
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/www/myRailsApp/current#default:


  App root: /www/myRailsApp/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 3173    Sessions: 1       Processed: 1       Uptime: 3m 7s
    CPU: 70%     Memory  : 426M    Last used: 3m 7s ago
  * PID: 3194    Sessions: 1       Processed: 1       Uptime: 3m 1s
    CPU: 69%     Memory  : 361M    Last used: 3m 0s ago
  * PID: 3220    Sessions: 1       Processed: 1       Uptime: 2m 40s
    CPU: 67%     Memory  : 349M    Last used: 2m 39s ago
```

The logs (nginx, rails) do not show anything.

Versions:

```
Rails 4.1.0
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1
Passenger Version : 4.0.41
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

My main questions are:

1. What exactly is going on here?
2. How can I diagnose this more effectively?
3. How can I setup capistrano so that it deploys rapidly?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that something in a Capistrano deploy causes your apps (not Passenger itself) to do some heavy processing that takes 20 minutes. You can see that not only in the CPU usage, but also in the "Sessions: 1" label. This means that all those processes are, at that time, busy processing a request

The best way to diagnose this is to find out what your app is doing. Read [the Phusion blog](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/09/21/the-right-way-to-deal-with-frozen-processes-on-unix/) to learn how to do that. In particular, you can use the SIGQUIT trick to get a backtrace for your processes.

You can also run `passenger-status --show=requests` to see which requests your apps are stuck at.